# Qt5 How to call QApplication from another class?

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication

Hi I'm writing multilanguage application in Qt5. I want to access

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

localised in main.cpp from my Settings class.
I need this to perform 2 commands:

```
a.installTranslator();
a.removeTranslattor();
```

when I'm trying to do do this I'm getting errors:

```
C2228: left of '.installTranslator' must have class/struct/union
C2228: left of '.removeTranslator' must have class/struct/union
```

How can I call it?

Comment: might be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: please provide a [m(c)ve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have solved my issue. Now I'm getting QApplication by qApp class. Sorry, that I wasted your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the function you need, you have two options:

1. [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html) has several static methods, so you can call them from almost everywhere as long as you include the header.
2. As you already comment, [there is a global pointer qApp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#qApp) allowing further access to non static methods. This is becase a QApplication is a singleton in any Qt App.

Note, this is valid for Qt 4 and Qt 5.